# Two cyclic subgroups of $\mathsf{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ of the same order are conjugate

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, algebraic-groups

I tried to prove the following result, but I'm not totally sure the proof is correct or even that the stated result is true. Any help checking my work would be appreciated.

The result I want to prove is that for any prime $p\neq 2$ and any two cyclic subgroups $K,K'\leqslant \mathsf{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that $|K| = |K'|$, then there exists some $g\in \mathsf{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that ${}^gK = K'$.

First of all, we can reduce to checking that there exists some $h$ with ${}^hK = K'$, where now we only require $h\in \mathsf{SL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$. Indeed, if ${}^hK = K'$ then for some choice of generator $x\in K$, ${}^hx$ is a generator of $K'$. But then $x,{}^hx$ have entries in $\mathbb{F}_p$ and are conjugate in $\mathsf{SL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$, so by using the rational normal form we can find some $g\in\mathsf{SL}_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ such that ${}^gx = {}^hx$, but then clearly ${}^gK = {}^hK = K'$.

Now suppose first that $|K| = |K'|$ is divisible by $p$. Then $K$ contains an element of order $p$ which is necessarily unipotent and hence conjugate to the matrix
$$u := \begin{bmatrix}1&1 \\\\ 0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$
Thus after replacing $K$ and $K'$ by conjugates we can assume $u\in K,K'$. Since $K$ and $K'$ are Abelian we then have $K,K'\leqslant C(\langle u\rangle)$. But a direct computation with matrices shows $C(\langle u\rangle) = \{\pm 1\}\langle u\rangle$ which is cyclic and hence $K = K'$ since a cyclic group has a unique subgroup of a given order.

Now suppose $|K| = |K'|$ is coprime to $p$. Then $K,K'$ are semisimple and thus can be extended to Cartan subgroups $\overline{K},\overline{K}'\leqslant \mathsf{SL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$. Since $\mathsf{SL}_2$ is connected all Cartan subgroups are conjugate, so we can find some $g\in \mathsf{SL}_2(\overline{\mathbb{F}}_p)$ such that ${}^g\overline{K}=\overline{K}'$ and hence ${}^gK\leqslant \overline{K}'$. Since $\overline{K}'\cong \overline{\mathbb{F}}_p^*$ is locally cyclic, the subgroup generated by ${}^gK$ and $K'$ is a cyclic group and hence ${}^gK = K'$.

Comment: Isn't it also true for $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_2) \cong S_3$?

Comment: I guess the result is true, the fact that $p$ is a prime is needed in the case where $|K| = |K'|$ is divisible by $p$. In the argument you need to use the fact that $(\mathbb{F}_p,+)$ is cyclic. For $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_{p^2})$ the result is false. In the case where $|K| = |K'|$ is coprime to $p$, there is an elementary argument, using diagonalizability.